# Creating a generic function with a switch statement that executes different code based on the type passed in the parameters

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Currently I have a function that takes in 2 generics and based on those generics it does something:

```
func drawPath <T, U>(from: T, to: U) {

        switch (from, to) {
        case is JMapWaypoint, is JMapWaypoint:

            print("map")

        case is JMapDestination, is JMapDestination:
            print("destination")

        default:
            print("default")
        }  
    }
```

the issue is, on the case lines (ex.case is JMapDestination, is JMapDestination:), I get warnings:

> Case will never be executed
>    Cast from '(T, U)' to unrelated type'JMapDestination' always fails

If the parameters are generic, shouldn't I be able to pass anything?  I don't know why it's giving these warnings.

Comment: @Sweeper  it did, just accepted your answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a switch case, `,` actually means "OR". For example:

```
let a = 1
switch a {
    case 1, 3, 7:
        print("xxx") // this will be run if a is 1 or 3 or 7
    default: break
}
```

So your switch case of `is JMapWaypoint, is JMapWaypoint` means "`(from, to)` is of type `JMapWaypoint` or `(from, to)` is of type `JMapWaypoint`". Well, `(from, to)` is a tuple, so it can never be of type `JMapWaypoint`.

You should have written:

```
case is (JMapWaypoint, JMapWaypoint):
```

instead.

But anyway, this seems like you are abusing generics. If your method only works for two types, it's by definition not generic... You should just create 2 overloads of `drawPath`.